# How to check for an HTML element in a rich text field?

Tags: templating, richtext

I want to do something special in my template if there's an HTML table in the rich text field. I tried this:

```
{% if "</table>" in entry.richTextFieldHandle %}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do this? Or can you think of a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work if you first escape your string using Twig [`escape`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html) filter. Not exactly sure what's going on, but it'll only work for me if I make Twig double escape the string like so:

```
{% set strategy = 'html' %}
{% set doubleEscapedString = entry.richTextFieldHandle|escape(strategy) %}
{% set hasTable = '&lt;/table&gt;' in doubleEscapedString %}

<div class="{{ hasTable ? 'hasTable' : 'hasNoTable' }}">
    {{ entry.richTextFieldHandle }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks quite messy though so I'm gonna look for a better way!